# How to properly use joins on polymorphic association in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have a Model `Action` that has a

```
belongs_to :actor, polymorphic: true
```

that actor can be: a `Customer`, `Admin`, `Seller` or `Guest`.

I want to filter instances of `Action` to just the actions made by a particular `Seller` or `Guest`. How can I do that?

In a normal association, I would join the two tables, but this way, I don't know how properly do it.

Answer (score 9):

Hope this may helpful to you:-

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :actor, polymorphic: true

    scope :by_type, lambda { |type| joins("JOIN #{type.table_name} ON #{type.table_name}.id = #{Opinion.table_name}.opinionable_id AND #{Opinion.table_name}.opinionable_type = '#{type.to_s}'") }
end
```

Then call it like:-

```
Action.by_type(Seller).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"actions\".* FROM \"astions\" JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = actions.actorable_id AND actions.actorable_type = 'Seller'"
```

Or you can achieve by this:-

```
belongs_to :actor, :foreign_key => :actorable_id, polymorphic: true

Action.joins(:actor).where('actors.actorable_id = ? AND actors.actorable_type = ?', seller_id, 'Seller'})
```